# How to upload a filepath to local database and receive the file path when I click download button

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

The problem is when I am downloading the file, I can see the path in the download file. I am not getting the actual contents of the file inside.

When I am attaching a file called sample.txt and **the path for sample.txt** is`== C:\Users\smohan\Downloads\databse\LocalDataBaseAp\sample.txt`. I can see the path gets binded with my datagrid. But when I click the cell of the grid and download the same file. The file is downloading. But when I open.. The downloaded file I can see inside is missing the actual contents, but instead the path is saved as content (i.e.) **C:\Users\smohan\Downloads\database\LocalDataBaseAp\sample.txt**

What's wrong with my code?

```
 private void UploadAttachment(DataGridViewCell dgvCell)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            //Set File dialog properties
            fileDialog.CheckFileExists = true;
            fileDialog.CheckPathExists = true;
            fileDialog.Filter = "All Files|*.*";
            fileDialog.Title = "Select a file";
            fileDialog.Multiselect = true;

            if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                cncInfoDataGridView.Rows[dgvCell.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = fileDialog.FileName;
                SqlCeConnection cnn = new SqlCeConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.CncConnectionString);
                //FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileDialog.FileName);
                byte[] imgData;
                imgData = File.ReadAllBytes(fileDialog.FileName);}
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Download Attachment from the provided DataGridViewCell
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dgvCell"></param>
    private void DownloadAttachment(DataGridViewCell dgvCell)
    {

        string strId = cncInfoDataGridView.Rows[dgvCell.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
         string fileName = Convert.ToString(dgvCell.Value);

         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
         {

             byte[] objData;

             FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
             string fileExtension = fileInfo.Extension;

             //show save as dialog
             using (SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog())
             {
                 //Set Save dialog properties
                 saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Files (*" + fileExtension + ")|*" + fileExtension;
                 saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save File as";
                 saveFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;
                 saveFileDialog1.FileName = fileName;

                 if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                 {
                     string s = cncInfoDataGridView.Rows[dgvCell.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                     objData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
                     string strFileToSave = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                     File.WriteAllBytes(saveFileDialog1.FileName, objData);
                 }
             }
         }
     }

}
```

}

Comment: Hint for you to start: A file path is simply a string.

Comment: Is it a web application?

Comment: @AndrewBarber Please see the edited question i did that.. But when i am downloading i am getting the path saved in downloaded file

Comment: @Ghukas its a winform application

Comment: @AndrewBarber any idea.. now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand what you're doing now; So, here's the pertinent code part:

```
  objData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
```

The problem is I think you are misunderstanding what `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string)` does. It does not read a file's contents; it encodes the string you pass to it. So, you are writing your file path from your Grid - not the contents of the file. This is more like what you want:

```
  objData = File.ReadAllBytes(s);
```

That reads all the bytes from the file at the *path* you pass to it, returning a `byte[]`, as you were using.

Comment: Oh my God i cannot believe that .. i finished my project,... hahahhahhahaha.. thanks a lot.. I feel like a year passed. One more thing do i need to use `string strFileToSave = saveFileDialog1.FileName;` because it holding my location. Also how can i make in my grid-cellview just to see the filename. Not the entire path. Now its showing me the entire path. Any idea

Comment: @Milanphir In this case, no; you don't need `string strFileToSave = saveFileDialog1.FileName;`. You can just pass `saveFileDialog1.FileName` directly. As for the rest; that would be beyond the scope of this question. You'd need to change how you bind things, and be sure the full path is still stored somewhere you can access it.

Comment: Ok thanks. Could you tell me how can i show file name only on the column(gridview). I mean hiding the path from grid view and show only file name,

Comment: I don't really use DataGridViews, sorry. I'd search a bit on that.